# Error of iterations using $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, scope

It's my first time posting here so I hope you can help.

Im having a problem using $scope.$watch. The thing is that I want to control 2 DateTime Fields on a Form and when 1 of them change, calculate the difference between them in Days to fill another number input of the Form. The problem is that when I run the app and change a Date the consolo shows me this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9odev.jpg

Here is the code I use.

```
$scope.$watch(
             "vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia",
             function handleFechaChange(newValue, oldValue) {
                 console.log('newValue: ' + newValue + ', oldValue: ' + oldValue);
                 if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                     vm.calculoDecalaje();
                 }
             });

vm.calculoDecalaje = function () {
             vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia = moment(vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia);
             vm.siniestro.fechaComunicacion = moment(vm.siniestro.fechaComunicacion);
             vm.siniestro.decalaje = vm.siniestro.fechaComunicacion.value - vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia.value;
         }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop - let's step through what's happening here:

- `vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia` changes, causing your watch function (`handleFechaChange`) to be run.
- `handleFechaChange` calls `vm.calculoDecalaje();`.
- `vm.calculoDecalaje` changes `vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia`, causing your watch function to be run again, which causes `vm.calculoDecalaje` to be run again, which causes your watch function to run again...

After 10 digest cycles, Angular realizes that the values are never going to stabilize, so it kills the infinite loop to stop your browser from crashing. This is why you're getting the [infinite digest error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

My recommendation would be to change your `vm.calculoDecalaje` function so that it doesn't mutate the input values:

```
vm.calculoDecalaje = function () {
    vm.siniestro.decalaje = moment(vm.siniestro.fechaComunicacion).value - moment(vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia).value;
}
```

That way your user input remains the 'source of truth' on what goes in to the function (which I find a bit easier to keep track of), and you don't cause your watcher to spiral out of control.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will look at this, I didn't realize about that!

Comment: @Iraitz: I added a suggestion of how I'd go about fixing the issue. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: It works!! Thanks so much Joe Clay, you are like my Angel :)

Comment: @Iraitz: Very glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using $watch is not recommended, I suggest you to use `ng-change` in your template on both fields instead.

Comment: Ng-Change can be used on DateTimePicker Fileds? I tried it but doesn't works.

Comment: Yep, but you are working with inputs, my fields are <datetimepicker...></datetimepicker>

Comment: yes it works. You should just configure it as `<datetimepicker data-ng-model="d1" data-ng-change="change()"></datetimepicker>`

Comment: For real, it's not working on me. Im doing it like that: <datetimepicker name="fechaOcurrencia" ng-change="vm.calculoDecalaje()" ng-model="vm.siniestro.fechaOcurrencia" date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" show-meridian="false" show-spinners="false"></datetimepicker>

Comment: For real, it's work. Did you to try to write `ng-change="vm.calculoDecalaje()"` instead of `data-ng-change="vm.calculoDecalaje()"` ?

You did not mention wish you package do you use, I supposed you used [dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

[poc](https://output.jsbin.com/dawome/6)

Answer (score 0):

Adding some info Joe Clay answer. The Angular runs digest loop because it can't tell that yours `fechaOcurrencia` and `fechaComunicacion` are stable, because you create new `moment` object every time. Angular treats it as new value. You should google for phrases "memoization angular" to find multiple examples how to solve your problem.